# Using R, as.POSIXct() returning NAs even though it was working before

Tags: r, date, time, posixct, posixlt

I am using R. This worked for me a month ago, but now when I try to run it I get NA. I have tried changing the timezone and I still receive NA. I am not sure why I am getting this issue

```
as.POSIXct("12:46 29-Nov-18",format = "%H:%M %m/%d/%y")
as.POSIXct("12:46 29-Nov-18",format = "%H:%M %m/%d/%y",tz= "GMT")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things wrong with your code, most of it fixed by reading [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html):

- `"%m"` is the 2 digit (0-padded) integer for the month, not `Nov`, use `%b` instead
- the string as dashes, not slashes, so `%m/%d/%y` should be `%m-%d-%y`
- the string has date first, so `%d-%m-%y` would have been the correct order.

Combine those three, and we have

```r
as.POSIXct("12:46 29-Nov-18",format = "%H:%M %d-%b-%y")
# [1] "2018-11-29 12:46:00 EST"
as.POSIXct("12:46 29-Nov-18",format = "%H:%M %d-%b-%y", tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2018-11-29 12:46:00 GMT"
```